# Workaround if the Application is Down

Tags: asp.net

We have deployed an application on the server.
Problem is, sometimes the application will be down due to some issue (Ex: While Downloading huge volume of data into Excel).
The application will be up after manually restarting the IIS.
We are creating a new application, so we are not working to fix this issue.
As a workaround, we are trying to build an exe with the below requirement:
Ping the application deployed on the server and find out whether the application is up or down, If the application is down, restart IIS.

Is it possible to ping a local website on the IIS? Is there any other way to do a temporary fix?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, that kind of stability isn't good.  However, you're interested in monitoring a URL and determining whether it is active...

TBH, I'm sure there are a few monitoring applications knocking around, some even free if that's you thing that will recognise specific ports and utilise appropriate protocols such as HTTP.  But if you fancy having a go yourself you could always utilise the HttpWebRequest to mock up a request to the server and hopefully it will respond in a timely manner.  Typically if you're just touching the server you can utilise a 'HEAD' request you just receives the header data rather than all the data.  Check out this [example](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4654/asynchronous-httpwebrequest/).